# Close infowindow when another marker is clicked

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have the following code to open an infowindow when a specific marker is click and it open a window. Does anyone know how to close the previous infowindow when another one is clicked?.

```
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map1, marker);
        });
```

Comment: Can you show us more of the code, e.g. where is infowindow first created?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110956/close-other-infowindows-nicely?rq=1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567280/google-api-v3-multiple-infowindows-plus-close-on-click/12567780#12567780

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just make sure you only create ONE `infoWindow` in the global scope, like this:

```
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow; //static infoWindow for all your markers
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
   //create your markers here
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
               infoWindow.open(map1, marker); //take care with case-sensitiveness
          });
});
```

**UPDATE**:

- Fix case sensitive spotted by Duncan.
- Illustrate the marker click handlers must be connected after marker creation, both inside page load event.

Comment: should be infoWindow.open as Javascript is case-sensitive

Comment: All the markers are created on page load thats why it doesnt work :)

Comment: @user1292656 put all in your page load handler, minus the infoWindow declaration, that remains at the root of your js file.

Answer (score 10):

Create a global variable in your JS file, name it lastOpenedInfoWindow or whatever you want, after that close it before opening a new info window, assign the "lastOpenedInfoWindow" to the currently opened window and so on

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, content, infowindow) {
        return function() {
            closeLastOpenedInfoWindow();
            infowindow.setContent(content);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            lastOpenedInfoWindow = infowindow;
        };
    })(marker, makrerdata[i], infowindow));
}


function closeLastOpenedInfoWindow() {
    if (lastOpenedInfoWindow) {
        lastOpenedInfoWindow.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make Sure you've one instance of InfoWindow -  new google.maps.InfoWindow. Therefore, everytime the marker is clicked open that only one instance declared either in your initialize method or globally declared InfoWindow.

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow
Make sure this infoWindow instantiated only once. Otherwise, you'll have multiple windows open eachtime you click the marker.

```
marker.addListener('click', function () {                                
    infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
    infoWindow.open(clntLocMap, marker);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`infowindow.close()` will close an open infowindow.  It depends on how you're creating your infowindows though - do you only have one infowindow variable to handle all, or are you creating multiple infowindow objects for each marker?  Hard to be more specific without seeing more of your code at this stage.

Comment: Yes i am using the same variable to handle all :)

Comment: google maps v3 doesnt work, please specify versions.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, here is what I did:

```
function initMap() {
//---------------------map
var options = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: {
        lat: 43.5963020324707,
        lng: 1.4221688508987427
    }
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);    
//--------------- Adresses
let addresses = [
    "23 Quai Lucien Lombard",
    "18 Place Laganne",
    "266 Avenue de Fronton",
    "3 Impasse du Professeur Nougayrol",
    "1 Allées Charles de Fitte",
    "5 Avenue de Casselardit",
    "84 Chemin des Argoulets"
];

// ---------------- globales
let markers = []
let infowindowArray = []

// ---------------- Adresses Géocoder
geocodeAdresses(addresses)
    .then(res=>{

        geocodeAdressesArray = res;         
        return geocodeAdressesArray
    })
    .then(geocodeAdressesArray=>{
    // --------------create markers
        for (let i = 0; i < geocodeAdressesArray.length; i++){  

            let marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
                'id': geocodeAdressesArray[i].id,
                'adresse': geocodeAdressesArray[i].adresse,
                'position':{
                    'lat':geocodeAdressesArray[i].lat,
                    'lng':geocodeAdressesArray[i].lng
                }
            });
            markers.push(marker)// push globale             
            marker.setMap(map)
    // ---------- create infowindows

            let infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                'position' : marker.position,                
                'content': marker.adresse,
            });
            infowindowArray.push(infowindow) // push globale
        }
    // ---------------close infowindows on clic 
        for (let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            let marker = markers[i];

            marker.addListener( 'click', ()=>{                  

                for (let j = 0; j < infowindowArray.length; j++) { 
                    let infowindow = infowindowArray[j];
                    infowindow.close(map, marker)
                }
                let currentInfowindows = infowindowArray[i]
                currentInfowindows.open(map)               
            })
        }
    })
```

}

For my geocodeAdresses (addresses), this is a function that I created from google geocode API.

I hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

You can use directly the `marker` with an arrow function as a callback if you have any issue with 'this' (in my case i'm using Vue.js). See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows).

In my case i have (make sure to create a marker, content and having this.mapsInfoWindow globally instantiated, and btw not need to set its content) :

```
...
marker.addListener("click", () => {
    if (this.mapsInfoWindow) {
        this.mapsInfoWindow.close();
    }
    this.mapsInfoWindow.setContent(content);
    this.mapsInfoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

In order to close the previous infowindow when another one is clicked, you need to make sure the following code is in the function initialize() loop.

infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;